# Problema con while dentro de otro while, python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, while

Ya usé continue, pero me deja justo despues del segundo while, por lo que me lee ""print (1.- Cuadrada)"". Y probé con break, pero se devuelve al inicio del todo. La idea es que al salir de ese while me lleve hacia el print de más abajo. Gracias!

```
salir = False
opcion = 0

while not salir:

    print("1.- Realizar cotización.")
    print("2.- Salir.")
    opcion = menu()
    print("\n")

    if opcion == 1:
        salir2 = False
        print("Nueva Cotización:")
        print("Ingrese forma de la Mesa")
        while not salir2:
            print("1.- Cuadrada.")
            print("\n")
            opcion2 = menu()
            if opcion2 == 1:
                print("Ingrese tamaño del lado en cm:")
                lado = int(input())
                continue  # problema
            else:
                continue  # problema
        print("Ingrese tipo de madera")  # .....
```

Comment: `continue` no sirve para lo que buscas, simplemente detiene la ejecución de esa iteración y hace que el ciclo inicie una nueva. En cambio `break` rompe el segundo ciclo `while` solamente  y **realiza** el `print ("Ingrese tipo de madera")`, hecho esto vuelve a realizar otra iteración del primer `while`. Realmente, es lo mismo que si haces que la variable de control sea `True`, `salir2 = True`.  No termino de ver cual es el problema usando `break` o modificando la variable de control, si una vez que entre en el segundo ciclo no quieres volver nunca más al primero basta con hacer `salir = True`.

Comment: para salir del `while` que quieres debes setear `salir2 = True`

Comment: Realmente no se entiende que es lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Por favor no coloques `SOLUCIONADO` al título de tu pregunta, si ya tienes la solución entonces compartela abajo en la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 0):

En caso de que el break no funcione simplemente debes poner que la condición del while se rompa. En este caso es que salir2 sea True, por lo que puedes cambiarla y así romper el ciclo

```
salir = False
opcion = 0

while not salir:

    print("1.- Realizar cotización.")
    print("2.- Salir.")
    opcion = menu()
    print("\n")

    if opcion == 1:
        salir2 = False
        print("Nueva Cotización:")
        print("Ingrese forma de la Mesa")
        while not salir2:
            print("1.- Cuadrada.")
            print("\n")
            opcion2 = menu()
            if opcion2 == 1:
                print("Ingrese tamaño del lado en cm:")
                lado = int(input())
                salir2 = True
            else:
                continue  # problema
        print("Ingrese tipo de madera")  # .....
```

Answer (score 0):

El código adjunto pide y valida cada opción. En cada caso se ofrece la opción de "Salir" al nivel anterior.

El patrón usual para operaciones repetitivas de largo indefinido es encerrar todo en un `while True:` y dentro del bloque evaluar cuando salir, lo que se logra ejecutando un `break`.

Si la opción ingresada no es válida, se muestra un mensaje de error y se pasa al siguiente ciclo.

```
while True:

    print("1.- Realizar cotización.")
    print("2.- Salir.")
    opcion = menu()

    if opcion == 1:
        print("Nueva Cotización:")
        while True:
            print("Ingrese forma de la Mesa")
            print("1.- Cuadrada.")
            print("2.- Redonda.")
            print("")
            print("9.- Salir.")
            opcion2 = menu()
            if opcion2 == 1:
                lado = int(input("Ingrese tamaño del lado en cm:"))
                break
            elif opcion2 == 2:
                diametro = int(input("Ingrese diametro en cm:"))
                break
            elif opcion2 == 9:
                break
            else:
                print("Opción no reconocida")

        tipo = input("Ingrese tipo de madera ")
    elif opcion == 2:
        break
    else:
        print("Opción no reconocida.")
```

**Prueba**

```
1.- Realizar cotización.
2.- Salir.
? 1
Nueva Cotización:
Ingrese forma de la Mesa
1.- Cuadrada.
2.- Redonda.

9.- Salir.
? 3
Opción no reconocida
Ingrese forma de la Mesa
1.- Cuadrada.
2.- Redonda.

9.- Salir.
? 1
Ingrese tamaño del lado en cm:10
Ingrese tipo de madera pino
1.- Realizar cotización.
2.- Salir.
? 3
Opción no reconocida.
1.- Realizar cotización.
2.- Salir.
? 2

Process finished with exit code 0
```